# Can I use weapons above my combat level?

Tags: stardew-valley

Every weapon has a "level". Does this mean I can't use that weapon if my combat level is below the weapon's level? If not, what does the weapon level mean?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can safely equip any weapon anytime in the game, regardless of the level of the weapon. The number shown is purely informational, and its only purpose is to show the effectiveness of a weapon compared to another one. There is no correlation between your weapon's level and your character.